# How can i use white spaces in bindingsource.filter?

Tags: c#, .net, bindingsource

I have:

- a datagridview (datagridview1).
- a column in datagridview1 named Phone Number.
- a bindingsource named (bindingsource1).

This code

```
bindingsource1.Filter="Phone Number = 123";
```

does not work because there's white space between phone and number!

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use square brackets

```
bindingsource1.Filter="[Phone Number] = 123";
```

or, preferably, don't use spaces in field-names.